# Equivariant resolution of singularities

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, resolution-of-singularities, equivariant

I am looking for some references on equivariant resolution of singularities. In most references quoted on mathoverflow (for instance : [Reference on an equivariant resolution of singularities](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/70061/reference-on-an-equivariant-resolution-of-singularities)), they only talk about finite group action (if I am not mistaken).

I was wondering if it is known that equivariant resolutions do not exist in general for larger group (are there counter-examples?). I am especially interested when the group is $\mathbb{C}^*$.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Equivariant resolutions exist for the action of any algebraic group. See, for example, 3.9.1 in Kollar's book "Lectures on resolution of singularities".

Comment: @ulrich Thanks! I still wonder why many papers only deal with finite group actions. But that does not really matter, now I have this reference.

Comment: I've need to reference this in a paper and used: Cor 7.6.3, O. E. Villamayor U. Patching local uniformizations. Ann. Sci. E ́cole Norm. Sup. (4), 25(6):629–677, 1992.

Comment: @ulrich In the proof of the proposition 3.9.1, it seems that for Kollar, a group action is, in particular a smooth morphism $G\times X\rightarrow X$, or am I mistaken ? (or maybe for him smooth morphism only means that any fiber is smooth??)

Answer (score 6):

To any variety $X$ over a field of characteristic zero, say $k$, one can attach a resolution of singularities, say $X'\to X$, with the following properties:

1. $X'\to X$ is an isomorphism over $X_{\mathrm{reg}}$.
2. if $\Theta:X\rightarrow Y$ is an isomorphism of schemes (not necessarily defined over $k$), then $\Theta$ can be extended to an isomorphism $\Theta':X'\rightarrow Y'$ compatible with $\Theta$ and the resolutions.

It follows from 1. and 2. that if $\Psi:Y\rightarrow Z$ is a second isomorphism of schemes, then $(\Psi\circ\Phi)'$ and $\Psi'\circ\Phi'$ coincide on the inverse image of $X_{\mathrm{reg}}$ in $X'$, and hence they coincide on $X'$. With a similar argument, we have $(\mathrm{id}_X)'=\mathrm{id}_{X'}$. In particular, if $G$ is any group of automorphisms of $X$ (not necessarily defined over $k$), the action of $G$ on $X$ can be lifted to an action on $X'$.

For a reference, see:

O. Villamayor: Equimultiplicity, algebraic elimination, and blowing-up. *Adv. in Math.* 262 (2014) 313-369. ([ArXiv link](https://arxiv.org/abs/1312.7836), [DOI link](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.aim.2014.04.013))